# Are there romanization preferences for tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

Are there romanization preferences for this site's tags? Do we have a system at all?

### Ju v. Jiu

These are how site tags are currently defined:

- 柔術 [jiujitsu](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jiujitsu) (active), [jujutsu](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jujutsu) (active) <- [jujitsu](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jujitsu) (synonym)
- 柔道 [judo](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/judo)

According to the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brazilian_jiu-jitsu) for [brazilian-jiu-jitsu](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brazilian-jiu-jitsu):

> "Jiu-Jitsu" is an older romanization that was the original spelling of the art in the West, and it is still in common use, where as the modern Hepburn romanization is "jūjutsu".

Using this the older romanization, judo should be "jiudo".

At a minimum, we should standardize on a tag for jujutsu, which currently has multiple tags. Even if we have a different romanization for the Brazilian variety, at least there is a one-to-one tag mapping between tag and concept.

### Wade Giles v. Pinyin

Similarly, we have

- 太极 (simplified)
- 太極 (traditional)

Our tag for this is [tai-chi](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tai-chi), which uses the Wade Giles romanization. The pinyin romanization is "taiji".

We use the more modern pinyin romanization for [bagua](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bagua), not the Wade Giles "pakua".

It may also be that we simply use what is more recognizable in English, independent of romanization. [wing-chun](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wing-chun), for example, is "yong chun" in pinyin, which I find unrecognizable.

Comment: I say we go with what's most common in English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the most common English used term, with synonymous tags for the rest.

Answer (score 2):

It's more problematic that this b/c there have been significant publications using the old spellings. (Pakua vs. Bagua, as an example.)

My sense is we'd need tag synonyms for something like that.

*With names, it can get even more complicated b/c conventions have shifted over time, and not everyone likes the new, and, if it's your name, you get to choose.*